# Discord.js Invalid Form Body limit: int value should be less than or equal to 100.error when using bulkDelete()

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I got this as the command code:

```
    if(!args[0]){
        message.channel.send(client.cmdlines.wrongUsage);
    }else if(args[1]){
        message.channel.send(client.cmdlines.wrongUsage);
    }else{
        if(message.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')){
            if(!isNaN(args[0])){
                message.channel.bulkDelete(args[0]+1).then(msg => {
                    message.channel.send(`Deleted ${args[0]} messages.`).then(msg => msg.delete({ timeout: 3000 })).catch(e => console.log(e));
                });
            }else{
                message.channel.send(client.cmdlines.wrongUsage);
            }
        }else{
            message.channel.send(client.cmdlines.missingPerms);
        }
    }
}
```

and for some reason im getting the:  Invalid Form Body
limit: int value should be less than or equal to 100.
error. Does somebody know what possible the problem could be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s in the error.. discord.js doesn’t allow you to bulk delete more than 100 messages at a time. Run a function to determine how many times you would need to cycle through to delete all the desired messages (`Math.floor(args[0]/100`). Then, you’ll need to delete the number of messages left from the 100. (`args[0] - Math.floor(args[0])*100`)

Cycle through deleting 100 messages the first value of times, then after delete messages the second value.

Oh, and make sure to parse `args[0]` into an int, first

Comment: The weird thing this exact code worked before and im only trying to delete 10 messages

Comment: okay Ive fixed the issue, I just needed to add let x = parseInt(args[0]); and that solved it. I'll also add a fixed for the 100 message limit

Comment: Yep, just like I said at the end of the message lol.

Comment: Just a minor suggestion: the 100 limit is from the API, not an arbitrary limit set by discord.js.