# Is there any way to delete more than 100 messages at once in Discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

currently im making a Discord Bot but im having troubles, I don't know how to delete more than 100 messages in discord.js, since limit its 100, Im looking for functions that will help me with my issue, my current code its:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const { Client, MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
  name: "purge",
  alias: [],
  devOnly: false,
  guildOnly: true,
  nsfwOnly: false,
  botPermissions: [
    "SEND_MESSAGES",
    "ATTACH_FILES",
    "VIEW_CHANNEL",
    "MANAGE_MESSAGES",
  ],
  userPermissions: ["SEND_MESSAGES", "MANAGE_MESSAGES"],
  category: "Moderation",
  usage: "clear (messages)",
  description: "Deletes the specified amount of messages",
  run: async (client, message, args) => {
    let prefix = await client.prefix(message);
    let member = message.mentions.members.first();

    if (!message.guild.me.permissions.has("MANAGE_MESSAGES"))
      return message.channel.send(
        new Discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setDescription(
            `<:no:860978971771928647> ***I don't have the necessary permissions to do that, please use the command \`${prefix}setup\` to check all it's working correctly.***`
          )
          .setColor(16711680)
      );

    if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES"))
      return message.channel.send(
        new Discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setDescription(
            "<:no:860978971771928647> ***You don't have the necessary permissions to do that.***"
          )
          .setColor(16711680)
      );

    if (member) {
      const userMessages = (await messages).filter(
        (m) => m.author.id === member.id
      )

      await message.channel.bulkDelete(userMessages)
      message.channel.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setDescription(`<:si:860978510079852544> ***${member} messages has been cleared.***`)
        .setColor('GREEN')
      )
    } else {
      let mensajes = parseInt(args[0]);
      if (!mensajes)
        return message.channel.send(
          new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setDescription(
              "<:no:860978971771928647> ***Please provide a amount of messages to delete, it needs to be a number***"
            )
            .setColor(16711680)
        );
      if (mensajes < 1)
        return message.channel.send(
          new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setDescription(
              "<:no:860978971771928647> ***The arguments provided are not correctly, the amount of messages must be greater than 1***"
            )
            .setColor(16711680)
        );
      let embedlimitmessages = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setDescription(
          "<:no:860978971771928647> ***You can't delete more than 100 messages**"
        )
        .setColor(16711680);
      if (mensajes > 100) return message.channel.send(embedlimitmessages);
      message.delete();
      message.channel.bulkDelete(mensajes);
      let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setDescription(
          `<:si:860978510079852544> ***I deleted ${mensajes} messages successfully!***`
        )
        .setColor("GREEN");
      message.channel.send(embed).then((m) => m.delete({ timeout: 10000 }));
    }
  },
};
```

I was reading in other forums for how to do it, also I looked up in Discord Help Servers, and they say with a for or a while i can do that to don't make API abuse, i would appreciate you guys can give me an example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.js Invalid Form Body limit: int value should be less than or equal to 100.error when using bulkDelete()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66791187/discord-js-invalid-form-body-limit-int-value-should-be-less-than-or-equal-to-10)

Comment: No, it dont's. Im trying to delete more than 100 messages with bulkDelete(); im having no errors

Comment: Have you ever attempted to delete more than 100 messages at once? It should throw an error or otherwise fail as you described.

Comment: And more importantly, the question I provided in the link above has a solution in the answer section that should solve your problem.

Comment: yes, i tried to delete more than 100 and i get an error, also, please read, because its not a problem, im searching for a function to delete more than 100 messages with bulkDelete

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE**: you should still keep a max amount on this

```js
Discord.TextChannel.prototype._bulkDelete = async function(amount) {
    if(amount > MAX_HERE) return;
    for (let i = amount; i > 0; i-=100) {
        if (i > 100) { 
            this.bulkDelete(100);
        } else {
            this.bulkDelete(i)
        }
    }
}
//you can now call the function on a text channel and put more than 100 if your new cap is higher
```

This code is creating an `_bulkDelete` method for all Discord text channels. I did not test this however, so if you get any errors, just tell me!

Notes: Replace `MAX_HERE` with your new cap. You may also get ratelimited. Maybe you want to add a "sleep" function to avoid being ratelimited.